# Different image path for capture and upload option using cordova , android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, image-uploading

I am working on an android app. There is an option to take pic to capture image using camera , and choose existing to take image from mobile. But when i try to get the path to pass to server, its showing different location

**capture image** : here i am getting exact path or fullPath like `file:///storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/13212343.jpg`

**Choose existing** : here i am getting uri like `content://media/external/images/media/4572`

So Is it possible to send this path to server ? If I send Like this , Java Program can identify this file ? Please help me. I want to send 2 parameters with image to backend.

```
uploadSubmit() This is the function for send to servlet.
```

**my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ran Sample Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //js

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

    // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // Cordova is ready to be used!
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        // Get image handle
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        document.getElementById("section3_part1").style.display= 'none';
        document.getElementById("section3_part2").style.display='block';
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo ...  The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
        xyz = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    function capturePhoto() {
        // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    function getPhoto(source) {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessFun, onFail, { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });

    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('back to home: ' + message);
    }

    function uploadSubmit(){
        var uploadingImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
        var imgUrl = uploadingImage.src;

        //alert("upload submition started third"+ FILE_URI);
        options = new FileUploadOptions();

        // parameter name of file:
        options.fileKey = "my_image";

        // name of the file:
        options.fileName = imgUrl.substr(imgUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        // mime type:
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        params = { val1: "some value", val2: "some other value" };
        options.params = params;
        ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imgUrl, "http://externalurl.com/uploadServlet", success, fail, options);
    }

    function success(message) {
        alert("Your photo uploaded successfully.");
    }
    function fail(message) {
        alert("Failed because: " + message);
    }


//ready function starts

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#section1').animate({ "top": "0px" }, 300);

//image rotaion
    var rotation = 0;
    jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $('#largeImage').css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    var autoHgt = $('#largeImage').height;
    $(' .imageBox').css({"height": autoHgt});
    };
    $('.leftRotation').click(function() {
        rotation -= 90;
        $('#largeImage').rotate(rotation);
    });
    $('.rightRotation').click(function() {
        rotation += 90;
        $('#largeImage').rotate(rotation);
    });


// section 2 popup
    $("#section2_Popup").bind( "click", function() {
        $('#section1').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section2').animate({ "top": "0px" }, 300);
        $('#section3').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section4').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $("#section1").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section2").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#section3").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section4").css({"display":"none"});
    });
// section 3 part 1 popup
    $( "#section3_Popup" ).bind( "click", function() {
        var usrName = $("#inUserName").val();
        $('#section1').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section2').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section3').animate({ "top": "0px" }, 300);
        $('#section4').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $("#section1").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section2").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section3").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#section4").css({"display":"none"});
        displayName(usrName);
    });
// section 3 part2 popup
    $( "#uploadImg" ).bind( "click", function() {
        $('#section1').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section2').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section3').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section4').animate({ "top": "0px" }, 300);
        $("#section1").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section2").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section3").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section4").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#section3_part1").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#section3_part2").css({"display":"none"});
    });

    // section 3 part2 popup cancel
    $( "#cancelUpload" ).bind( "click", function() {
        $('#section1').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section2').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section3').animate({ "top": "0px" }, 300);
        $('#section4').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $("#section1").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section2").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section3").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#section4").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section3_part1").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#section3_part2").css({"display":"none"});
    });

    //back button 
    $( "#backBtn" ).bind( "click", function() {
        $('#section1').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section2').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $('#section3').animate({ "top": "0px" }, 300);
        $('#section4').animate({ "top": "-999px" }, 300);
        $("#section1").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section2").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section3").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#section4").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#section3_part1").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#section3_part2").css({"display":"none"});
    });

    // name display
    function displayName(userName){
        var element=document.getElementById("user_name");
        element.innerHTML="Welcome "+userName;
        var element=document.getElementById("hiddenname");
        element.value=userName;
    }

    // input box image from library

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#largeImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $('#section3_part1').css({'display':'none'});
                $('#section3_part2').css({'display':'block'});
                $('#largeImage').css({'display':'block'});
            }
           // reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("#inputFile").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

 });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            position: relative;
        }
        #section2, #section3, #section4, #section3_part2{
            display: none;
        }
        #section1, #section2, #section3, #section4{
            position: absolute;
            top: -999px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #largeImage{
            display:none; 
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
        }
        .imageBox{
            width:80%;
            height:auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="section1">
        <span id="section2_Popup">START</span>
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
        Enter Name:  <input type="text" id="inUserName" placeholder="Enter your Name" required min="3"/> <button id="section3_Popup">Go</button>
    </div>
    <div id="section3">
        <div id="section3_part1">
            <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button><br>
            <!-- <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br> -->
            <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br> 
            <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
            <input type="file" name="From Mobile" id="inputFile"/>
        </div>
        <div id="section3_part2">
            <div class="imageBox">
                <img id="largeImage" src="index.png" />
            </div>
            <span class="leftRotation">left</span> <span class="rightRotation">right</span>
            <button id="uploadImg">Upload</button>
            <button id="cancelUpload">cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section4">
        <div id="user_name"></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenname" />
        Email id* : <input type="text" id="emailid" placeholder="Enter Email id" /><br/>
        Phone* : <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number" /><br/>
        Caption (optional) : <input type="text" id="captn" placeholder="Enter a caption" /><br/>
        <button id="submitBtn" onClick="uploadSubmit()">SUBMIT</button>
        <button id="backBtn">BACK</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the exact location you can make use of filesystem api in phonegap. So your upload code will look like

```
 var fileuri ="";
 function uploadSubmit(){
    var uploadingImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    var imgUrl = uploadingImage.src;
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imgUrl , resolveOnSuccess, fsFail);
    options = new FileUploadOptions();
    // parameter name of file:
    options.fileKey = "my_image";
    // name of the file:
    options.fileName = imgUrl.substr(imgUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    // mime type:
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    params = { val1: "some value", val2: "some other value" };
    options.params = params;
    ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileuri , "http://externalurl.com/uploadServlet", success, fail, options);
}

function success(message) {
    alert("Your photo uploaded successfully.");
}
function fail(message) {
    alert("Failed because: " + message);
}

function resolveOnSuccess(entry) {
   fileuri = entry.toURL();
   //use fileuri to upload image on server 
}

function fsFail(message) {
alert("Error Message: " + message+ "Error Code:" +message.target.error.code);
}
```

Comment: window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imgUrl , resolveOnSuccess, fsFail); is not running. I am new to cordova, please  tell me how to get it .

Comment: have u added file plugin ??

Comment: Check this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem)

Comment: file plugin ? are to talking about config.xml file ?

Comment: I am using version 2.9.0 , so i added 
<plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils" />
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer" />

Comment: I am not getting any error , after "var imgUrl = uploadingImage.src;" program get stops. its not executing after this  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imgUrl , resolveOnSuccess, fsFail); 

How to saw error in emulator ? i checked this after downloading apk

Comment: i am getting image from input element but it is not working what to do?